# How to put mnemonic under the second instance of a Character (Java-Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mnemonics

I have a `JButton` named button1 with text "Alter Today".

I want to set a mnemonic under 'T' in the word 'Today' of this button (that is second instance of 't' or 'T' in 'Alter Today').

When I am trying to do:

```
button1.setMnemonic(6);
```

I am not able to see underlined 'T'.

When I am doing:

```
button1.setMnemonic('T');
```

it is still underlining 't' in the word 'Alter'.

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
bt.setMnemonic('T');

bt.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(6);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: But, even here, we have to write both (bt.setMnemonic('T');

bt.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(6);)
 
Writing just one of those 2 statements doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

```
button.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(...);
```

Comment: That's the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton button = new JButton("Alter Today");
button.setMnemonic('T');
// or button.setMnemonic(6);
// or button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

Comment: Tried this. This one is underlining first instance of 'T'...not the second instance.

Comment: @Vikram How about `button.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);`

Comment: This will still do the first "t", in the word "Alter", not the "T" in the word "Today".